# The task "docs" could not be found. Did you mean "do"?

Tags: elixir, documentation, elixir-mix

How to generate documentation for mix project? How it can do it?

The procedure for working with the Elixir mix-project:

- I generate a project by `mix new greeter` command.
- I add a block of comments in the `greeter.ex` file.
- I add dependencies to the `mix.exs` file.
- I try to generate documentation by `mix docs`
  command.

`mix help` **can not** provide `docs` task in a list of possible options:

```
mix                   # Runs the default task (current: "mix run")
mix app.start         # Starts all registered apps
mix app.tree          # Prints the application tree
mix archive           # Lists installed archives
mix archive.build     # Archives this project into a .ez file
mix archive.install   # Installs an archive locally
mix archive.uninstall # Uninstalls archives
mix clean             # Deletes generated application files
mix cmd               # Executes the given command
mix compile           # Compiles source files
mix deps              # Lists dependencies and their status
mix deps.clean        # Deletes the given dependencies' files
mix deps.compile      # Compiles dependencies
mix deps.get          # Gets all out of date dependencies
mix deps.tree         # Prints the dependency tree
mix deps.unlock       # Unlocks the given dependencies
mix deps.update       # Updates the given dependencies
mix dialyzer          # Runs dialyzer with default or project-defined flags.
mix dialyzer.build    # Build the required plt(s) and exit.
mix dialyzer.clean    # Delete plt(s) and exit.
mix dialyzer.explain  # Display information about dialyzer warnings.
mix do                # Executes the tasks separated by comma
mix escript           # Lists installed escripts
```

When I run `mix docs` command I get a mix-message:

`**(Mix) The task "docs" could not be found. Did you mean "do"?`

```
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Dependency resolution completed:
Unchanged:
  earmark 1.3.2
  ex_doc 0.20.2
  makeup 0.8.0
  makeup_elixir 0.13.0
  nimble_parsec 0.5.0
All dependencies are up to date
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remove `_build` directory, remove all content of `deps` directory, remove `mix.lock`.

Then in a command line of mix-project I do commands:

1. `mix deps.clean --all`
2. `mix deps.update --all`
3. `mix deps.get --all`

After that, I run `mix docs` and documentation was generated.

Command `mix help docs` print ExDoc documentation too.

Answer (score 9):

The `mix docs` task is available with [ExDoc](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_doc/readme.html). Make sure that you have the dependency installed. Make sure to check out the docs and install it properly. Then you'll be able to use the `mix docs`  command.

This is how to install it:

- Add it to your dependencies in `mix.exs`:

for Elixir >= 1.7:

```
def deps do
  [
    {:ex_doc, "~> 0.19", only: :dev, runtime: false},
  ]
end
```

Elixir < 1.7:

```
def deps do
  [
    {:ex_doc, "~> 0.18.0", only: :dev, runtime: false},
  ]
end
```

- Run `mix deps.get`
- Run `mix docs`

There are things you can configure in the project function of your mix file. Such as the `name`, `source_url` and `homepage_url`. Make sure to check out ExDoc's documentation for more details.

Concerning the "task could not be found" error, `mix help` lists tasks for the **current** environment.  The default mix environment is `:dev`, and above `ex_doc` was added to the `:dev` environment.  However, [some projects](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/v2.14.2/mix.exs#L33) use a `:docs` environment, instead of `:dev`.

Also, mix tasks can be provided by compilation, so you may need compile first (also respecting the environment, as above).

So, if the `mix docs` task is not listed by `mix help` or "could not be found", be sure to run `mix compile` and `mix help` in the environment of the `ex_doc` dependency.  For example, run `MIX_ENV=docs mix compile`, then `MIX_ENV=docs mix help` or `MIX_ENV=docs mix docs`.

Comment: It should work like this, but for some reason it does not work.

Elixir version is 1.8.2. 

My mix.exs file contains (
```
def deps do
    [
     {:ex_doc, "~> 0.19", only: :dev, runtime: false},
  ]) 
```
 I try to do a description of https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/documentation/ material.

I have done all you describe.

Unfortunately, all this does not lead to the generation of documentation.

Comment: I read ExDoc documentation. I would like to see all options available when generating docs, run `mix help docs`. I can't - `** (Mix) The task "docs" could not be found. Did you mean "do"?`

Answer (score 1):

If you installed ex_doc with

```
{:ex_doc, "~> 0.19", only: :dev, runtime: false},
```

It will not work if you are running in `:prod` mode. You need to remove `only :dev`
from the line above.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error comes when we have a dependency which is available only for some environment like only :test or :dev
so to fix this issue please make sure that particular dependency is available in required environment

```
{:ex_doc, ">= 0.0.0", runtime: false}
```

Update it like this and it should solve the issue.

Comment: You can also uses `MIX_ENV=the-env mix ...`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was I had set `preferred_cli_env: [docs: :docs]` and yet `{:ex_doc, "~> 0.31", only: :dev, runtime: false},`

So `mix docs` was always using `MIX_ENV=docs` where `ex_doc` was not available.

Changing the `ex_doc` dependency to `only: :docs` fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

For my project `mix do docs` worked.

Comment: That is no different from `mix docs`.